# Resize divs with common edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is that possible to resize two divs simultaneously using their common edge using html and css only? Is there some Angular2 way to do it?

I tried play with `resize:vertical` style but without luck:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/qe014g6o/)

I was hoping that outer div could limit resizing but it seems I was wrong.

PS I don't want to use jquery or work with elements directly from code because I work with ng2 and it is not a good approach to use such hacks, but I didn't find such functionality in ng2

Comment: i don't think this is possible without 2 lines of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try ng2-split-pane. Not sure if this is what you need but there is a quick demo on the page that should clear that up.

It works by inserting a dragging anchor between two divs with the option of orienting them vertically or horizontally.

https://github.com/wannabegeek/ng2-split-pane

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried

```
 display: flex
 display: flex-box
```